# Adding Sub Title to AppBar in Scaffold

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-appbar

In my flutter app I have page with search functionality. It brings me some data from API server with bloc pattern implementation.
Now I need to add sub title with text "Recent Searches". While trying to add it overlays my "Enter text to search" text. I can't add it below appbar on top and left side of my screen
This is my current stage:

[image]
That what I want to add:

[image]

```
AppBar _appBar() {
  return AppBar(
   iconTheme: IconThemeData(
    color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8),
  ),
  title: TextField(
    onChanged: _textInputListener.add,
    autofocus: true,
    controller: _textInputController,
    key: Key('searchscreen_input_tf_id'),
    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      hintText: AppTranslations.of(context).text("enter_text_to_search"),
      border: InputBorder.none,
    ),
  ),
  actions: <Widget>[
    IconButton(
      key: Key('searchscreen_clear_ib_id'),
      icon: const Icon(
        Icons.clear,
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        if (_textInputController.text.isNotEmpty) {
          _textInputController.clear();
          _textInputListener.add("");
        }
      },
    )
  ],
);
}


Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Container(
  color: Color(0xFF131E42),
  child: SafeArea(
    child: Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      appBar: _appBar(),
      body: BlocBuilder(
        bloc: _searchScreenBloc,
        builder: (_, SearchScreenState state) {
          if (state is InitialSearchScreenState) {
            _searchScreenBloc.add(LoadRecent());
            return _containerWithPaddings(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
          if (state is SearchScreenRecentState) {
            return _recentList(state.securities);
          }
          if (state is SearchScreenLoadingDataState) {
            return _containerWithPaddings(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
          if (state is SearchScreenLoadedDataState) {
            return _loadedList(state.securities);
          }
          if (state is SearchScreenErrorState) {
            _searchScreenBloc.add(LoadSearchResult(securityName: _textInputController.text));
            return _containerWithPaddings(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
          if (state is SearchScreenNoResultsState) {
            return _containerWithPaddings(
                child: Text(
              AppTranslations.of(context).text("no_results"),
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18.0,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ));
          }

          throw ArgumentError('$state not in cases');
        },
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

Comment: when you are rendering results, in your ```ListView.builder``` you can conditionally render ```recent search``` widget with ```GestureDetector``` and the result only at index 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `bottom` property of `AppBar`.

**Code Sample**

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Title'),
          bottom: PreferredSize(
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Text('Bottom text'),
              ),
              preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(12.0)),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Try it on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/22a9492e6f75211a1ea141c338a7c74f)

**Screenshot**
[image]